# Modelling fault plane using TIN?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, 3d-analyst, tin

I am working on a project which runs on ArcGIS platform using VB.NET. It is to model a sub-surface fault plane (currently a plane rectangular model with some dip) and then to find required distances from various points on surface of the earth. These distances are not necessarily nearest distances.

One idea I got and decided to use is TIN network.

I want to know if this is productive given that the number of points I know on surface would be only 5.

Is there any better option to model this?

And one more point I want to remind is that we can not model perfectly vertical faults using that.

Answer (score 1):

You could programatically construct a 3D polygon by first creating vertices then 3D segments from vertices, then a polygon. (Never tried to create a 3D polygon but I was able to create an add-in for importing borehole logs and creting 3D polylines split up by assays so it may be possible to take it to the next step)

Another way of creating a 3D polygon is by deriving existing heights from a surface such as TIN or raster. You may run into the same 2.5 rendering limitations for perfectly vertical faults. Look into geological software such as [Geosoft Target](http://www.geosoft.com/products/target) which may be better suited for this type of work.