# Is extrusion of a line (which is curved) into a plane at a certain angle possible in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, vb.net, extrude

I have a polyline shape file which is a fault trace on earth's surface.

I want to extrude this into a 3-D plane at a certain angle (which is dip angle of the fault).

However, the extruded plane should start somewhere below the ground surface but not from the line itself.

I want to get it done in ArcGIS.

I am coding in VB.NET language

I am adding a rough 2-D representation to understand it better

[image]

Comment: Can you indicate which is the input and which is the output?

Comment: I have line shape file, the angle at which the plane should be formed (with horizontal), the distances from the line to the starting and ending points of required plane(Z1 and Z2 in figure) . Now I need to develop this plane and find some distances from various points on earth's surface (Like nearest distance from a point to the plane.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your input is Z1, and the angle; And you want the curved surface which is formed by Z1, Z2 & and the two curves?

Comment: Yes. Also I want to mention that I have only the shapefile of upper curve, which is like a surface trace of the plane that can be formed by the lower two curves.

Comment: Hi @DevdattaTengshe did you find something related to this? I have also tried to contact you on twitter and facebook!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in ArcGIS as ArcGIS is not a 3D but rather a 2.5D software as discussed here:

[How to set up a 3D plane in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98032/how-to-set-up-a-3d-plane-in-arcgis)

[What is a better idea for modelling a fault plane than as TIN?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101998/what-is-a-better-idea-for-modelling-a-fault-plane-than-as-tin)

You should try a specialized 3D geology & exploration software such as Geosoft Target or Leapfrog Mining.